# What are some practical uses of STDIN redirection?

Tags: io-redirection, stdin

I am having a very difficult time trying to think of a single practical use for STDIN redirection. `cat < /etc/passwd` is an example of STDIN redirection, but it is silly in the same way as a useless use of cat. I've used Linux for 15 years now and I can't think of a single time I've needed STDIN redirection. Does anyone have any practical examples of it?

Comment: Certainly in 15 years you must have used a pipe (`|`)? That's using stdin redirection.

Comment: with `cat < file` the shell attempts to do the open first. if file cannot be opened `cat` is never called at all. it is *at least* more efficient - which should definitely be a practical consideration.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple usecases, this is one of them. Applying a kernel patch:

```
cd linux-3.16.2 && patch -p1 < patch-3.16.2-3
```

Comment: I cannot upvote this, unfortunately. This is a great example.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, you're a teacher...!!!

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -p < sqlfile.sql 
sort < domain_list.txt > sorted_domain_list.txt
```

Counting words of a text:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# wc -c << EOF
>     This is a simple lookup program 
>     for good (and bad) restaurants
>     in Cape Town.
> EOF
90
```

Comment: The mysql example is a good one. The sort example, I'm not entirely sure how it differs from `sort domain_list.txt > sorted_domain_list.txt`

Comment: When you use `cmd1 < file1 > file2 ` ; at first file1 sent to cmd1 and their output sent to file2.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you’re asking specifically about redirecting a program’s stdin to a file,
with the `cmd < file` syntax.
I ask because your question, as asked, is somewhat ambiguous. 
After all, `cmd1 | cmd2`
is redirecting `cmd2`’s stdin, also.

1. When you need to get a program to read from a file
   when the program doesn’t take an input filename parameter. 
   As you pointed out, `cat < file`
   and `sort < file` are examples where **`<`** *isn’t* necessary,
   because you can say`cat file` and `sort file`. 
   fkraiem’s example of putting `ed` commands into a file
   and then saying `ed parameter_file < commands_file`
   is a great one.
2. When you need to get a program to read from a file
   when the program behaves differently if an input filename parameter is given
   versus when it is reading stdin. 
   The one example that I know of is `wc`,
   where `wc -l < filename` outputs `number_of_lines`,
   but `wc -l filename` outputs `number_of_lines   filename`, which is much harder to use in a script. 
   IMNSHO, this is a bug in `wc`, but there it is.
3. When you want to do something with values from a text file:

   ```
   while read var1 var2 …
   do
       code using var1, var2, etc…
             ︙
   done < file
   ```

Answer (score 2):

[Standard Input (stdin) Redirection](http://www.thegeekscope.com/io-redirection-of-stdin-stderr-and-stdout-in-linux/)

In Linux, cat command is used to print the content of a file. However, if cat command is executed without any input argument then by default it tries to read from the standard input (stdin) and because stdin is linked to the keyboard therefore it just waits for user to type something.

```
  # cat
   Hello World!    This is the input typed on the standard input
   Hello World!    This is the output printed by cat command on the standard output
```

We executed the cat command and then typed ‘Hello World!’. cat command accepted the text typed on the standard input and redirected the same to the standard output. This is why you are seeing the string ‘Hello World!’ twice. You need to press ctrl+D to gain the console access back.

Practical example :

```
          any_prog < inputfile 2>errorfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You typically want stdin redirection in order to send some file as an input to some command. This happens mostly in scripts, where you can have temporary results stored in a file. Depending on the context, one can either use a pipe (so that a temporary file isn't needed) or a temporary file with stdin redirection (an advantage is that controlling errors in a portable way via the exit status is easier).

Now, some commands can accept the input as an argument, and in such a case, stdin redirection isn't needed... in general. But what's interesting is one can have differences depending on how the input is provided, so that a useless use of `cat` can actually be useful. Let's take an example: `gzip`.

```
$ echo foo > text
$ gzip -k text
$ file text.gz
text.gz: gzip compressed data, was "text", last modified: Thu Sep 18 00:38:18 2014, from Unix
```

Here one gets the timestamp of the file `text`. Then, instead of providing the `text` filename as an argument, let's use a redirection:

```
$ gzip < text > text.gz
$ file text.gz
text.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Thu Sep 18 00:38:18 2014, from Unix
```

One still gets the same timestamp, but the original filename is no longer stored in the compressed file (the `was "text"` has disappeared). Now, let's use a pipe, with what seems to be a useless use of `cat`:

```
$ cat text | gzip > text.gz
$ file text.gz
text.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Thu Sep 18 00:43:46 2014, from Unix
```

This time, the timestamp has changed: it is the date/time when the gzip was executed, not the timestamp of the file `text`.

So, depending on what you want and the type of command, you have 3 different solutions that seem to be equivalent but actually give slightly different results.

Note: another example is the `lpr` printing command, for which you can use a redirection instead of a filename as an argument if you don't want the filename to leak in the printer queue.

Answer (score 2):

Good ol' `ed`:

```
$ cat file.txt 
foo
bar
baz
$ cat edcommands.txt 
,s/ba/ta/
w
q

$ ed file.txt < edcommands.txt 
12
12
$ cat file.txt 
foo
tar
taz
```

(Though of course for such a short command you would just do `printf ",s/ba/ta/\nw\nq" | ed file.txt`. ;) )